# How to display text of selected List item on dropDown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap dropDown html and I am trying to display the text of the selected item **Note:** I have a set of 3 dropDowns:

```
<ul id="filters" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="option-combo dropdown  Agency"> 
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle">
            Agency <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-filter-group="Agency">
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg selected" href="#filter-agency-TBWA">TBWA</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-agency-Ogilvy">Ogilvy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="option-combo dropdown Client"> 
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            Client <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" data-filter-value="">All</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-client-Sky" data-filter-value=".Sky">Sky</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-client-Vodafone" data-filter-value=".Vodafone">Vodafone</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="option-combo dropdown Year"> 
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            Client <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="filter option-set dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ref="#" data-filter-value="">All</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2013">2013</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2014">2014</a></li>
            <li><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#filter-year-y2012">2012</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery I tried with no luck:

```
$('.filter').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var $text = $(this).text();
    $(this).prev(".dropdown-toggle").text($text);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is cleaner than using parent() jquery because it finds the closest (traveling up the dom tree) class dropdown and then within that finds dropdown-toggle class (traveling down the tree). as long as your dropdowns all have class dropdown in the outer div and the dropdown-toggle in the inner div, it doesnt matter the order in which your html is structured:

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    var htmlText = text + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
});
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Like I said in my answer, "I'm sure there's a better way to do that.." :P

Comment: just to make it more useful for anyone coming to this question, see where you insert the span? Add an empty space before then span tag like " span Like that the .caret will keep the positioning as per bootstrap. Just for occasional newbies ;)

Answer (score 3):

This works, but it's ugly. Change:

```
$(this).prev(".dropdown-toggle").text($text);
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings(".dropdown-toggle").html($text + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do that, but since you're clicking on the `<a>` inside an `<li>` inside a `<ul>`, `.parent().parent()siblings()...` does the trick, as it will select the sibling of the `<ul>` that has a class of `.dropdown-toggle`, and change it's display text to that of the click `<a>` tag.

Hope that makes sense!

**Edited** to add the caret.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/XbQSqPcCr0)

Comment: Superb. Actually my "ugly" one wasn't even working and I do not understand why. However, your clean up works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: No problem, be sure to upvote and select as the answer so others can benefit from this. Cheers!

Comment: You can use `closest('.filter')` instead of chaining `parent()` call, but +1 either way.

Comment: Yup I will accept it as soon as it let me to. Upvote is there. One more question, can you see I have a span.caret? How can i keep that and only change the text? As at the moment the changes of text removes the span.caret too

Comment: maybe I should append the span after the text change? or is it there a better way?

Comment: ok i had to accept the other answer as it seems you agree with @TimLewis but thanks a lot. Yours works too

Comment: @rob.m Haha no problem, his **is** the better solution anyway :P

Answer (score 0):

Here a clean way to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/4g01b2tb/2/

```
$('.filter').click(function (event) {
    var targetText=event.target.text;
    $(this).prev('.btn').text(targetText);

});
```